# Host two different sites in apache

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I have one Linux server with Apache installed. I configured two sites in it using `VirtualHost`.

I configured the two `VirtualHosts` for two different domain names. The configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 12.123.123.123>
  ServerAdmin info@example-one.com
  ServerName example-one.com
  ServerAlias www.example-one.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example-one
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 12.123.123.123>
  ServerAdmin info@example-two.com
  ServerName example-two.com
  ServerAlias www.example-two.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example-two
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit my site `example-one.com`, then I see the correct website.

But when I visit `example-two.com`, then I see the website of `example-one.com`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to host those two different websites under the same Apache server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `NameVirtualHost` directive somewhere in your httpd config file?

This should work. Be aware that the first `VirtualHost` block is the default in case the http request does not match any other `VirtualHost` block.

For reference https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin info@example-one.com
  ServerName example-one.com
  ServerAlias www.example-one.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example-one
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin info@example-two.com
  ServerName example-two.com
  ServerAlias www.example-two.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example-two
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```